# Unit test issue when targeting different .net version

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm-light

My Visual Studio 2015 solution contains a Unit Test project targeting .NET 4.5.

The code I am testing is a .NET 4.0 WPF app. The platform difference is necessary so Visual Studio can recognize "async Task" test methods properly.

The WPF app project depends on MvvmLight NuGet package, so I also had to reference this package on the Unit Test project.

The Unit Test compilation fails since it expects MvvmLight 5.3.0.19038 while it contains reference to 5.3.0.19026.

I tried to manually edit packages.config file on the Unit Test project to make MvvmLight package (and its dependencies) target .NET 4.0, like:

```
  <package id="MvvmLight" version="5.3.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

However, the assembly is still the same.

How can compile this project?

Comment: just to clarify - you're using `async await` in your unit test project, but not your to be tested project?  Can you not upgrade the to be tested project to a similar framework? Or drop `async/await` from your tests?

Comment: I use async await in the to be tested project too. For this I use Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package. I cannot upgrade .NET version at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

I could workaround "async Task" test methods limitation on .NET 4.0 by creating tests like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        TaskEx.Run(async () =>
        {
            //Replace with unit test code
            await TaskEx.Delay(1000);

        }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

Still not sure if this will work for all tests, but it is a way to get started.